# Reading 'Contacts...' from an Exchange Appointment

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, ews-managed-api

In Outlook, I can open an appointment and follow File -> Properties in the ribbon to view the properties. In the properties window, there is the 'Contacts...' button and textbox where you can apply contacts to the appointment or enter text in the box.

I want to programmaticly read this property via the Exchange Managed API but can't find anything to support this.

Looking through the [Appointment documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.appointment_members%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx), I see members for just about all of the properties but don't see a way to retrieve the "Contacts".

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

look or do a google search on something like the following
not even sure this would work.. for contacts it would just replace Appoinment with Contact

```
Appointment apt = AppointMent.Bind(service, new ItemId(id), new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, AppointmentSchema.Body ));
```

Comment: Of source I've checked Google, I found plenty of examples like what you have. However, what I can't figure out is how to the the "Contacts".

Comment: Contacts cnt = Contacts.Bind(service, new ItemId(id) bla..bla..bla does that even work for you if you replace the code..? I will look real quick are you wanting to access the contacts/Appointments..? if you look at this page and scroll down a bit you can see an example of how to access it via a web application just make modifications to fit your use case http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2007/01/30/how-do-i-access-my-outlook-contacts-from-my-web-application.aspx

Comment: I'll test that over the weekend. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't work. The Id you bind to must match types with the object type.